# How does JS + Google People API work well for requestMask?

Tags: javascript, google-people-api

I hope you could help me to find what's wrong with that JS request to the Google People API. Generally it works well, but I just receive the standard information. The request masks doesn't change anything.

Regards!

```
var request = gapi.client.people.people.connections.list({
    resourceName: 'people/me',
    pageToken: pageToken,
    pageSize: 500,
    requestMask: {
        includeField: 'people.names,people.phoneNumbers.people.emailAddresses'
    }
});
```

Comment: Nobody out there may help?

Comment: What is **pageToken** in your example?

Answer (score 3):

There is probably a bug on the client library, the following works:

```
var request = gapi.client.people.people.connections.list({
    resourceName: 'people/me',
    pageToken: pageToken,
    pageSize: 500,
    'requestMask.includeField': 'people.names,people.phoneNumbers.people.emailAddresses',
    // ^^ note that the nested object is flattened
    requestMask: {
        includeField: 'people.names,people.phoneNumbers.people.emailAddresses'
    }
});
```

While just using the flattened key works today, it might be wise to define it using both patterns just in case Google fixes the client library.